# Push cell down automatically in excel (2010) table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I don't know if this is the right forum to ask this

I have the following table in excel it is formatted as a table except the total

```
 -----------------------------
| Item  | Description | Price |
 -----------------------------
| 1     | Descrip 1   | £1000 |
 -----------------------------
| 2     | Descrip 2   | £1000 |
 -----------------------------
| 3     | Descrip 3   | £1000 |
 -----------------------------
| 4     | Descrip 4   | £1000 |
 -----------------------------
              | Total | £4000 |
               ---------------
```

Say I want to add a new line, as I type it automatically adds the line being a table however it does not move cells below it down automatically as I would like the total row to go down and accommodate the new line in the table and update the total. How is this possible? E.G

```
 -----------------------------
| Item  | Description | Price |
 -----------------------------
| 1     | Descrip 1   | £1000 |
 -----------------------------
| 2     | Descrip 2   | £1000 |
 -----------------------------
| 3     | Descrip 3   | £1000 |
 -----------------------------
| 4     | Descrip 4   | £1000 |
 -----------------------------
| 5     | Descrip 5   | £1000 | < New line
 -----------------------------
              | Total | £5000 | < Total moves down and updates
               ---------------
```

Comment: Have you added that total yourself manually?  An excel table should have the total automatically calculated and placed there (it is toggleable via the table toolbar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a new worksheet.

Write down in the adjacent cells a part of your table, eg:

```
 -----------------------------
| Item  | Description | Price |
 -----------------------------
| 1     | Descrip 1   | £1000 |
 -----------------------------
| 2     | Descrip 2   | £1000 |
 -----------------------------
| 3     | Descrip 3   | £1000 |
 -----------------------------
| 4     | Descrip 4   | £1000 |
```

Select the cells and press `Ctrl+L` to create a list. In the dialog which appears be sure to check `"My list has headers"`. Press `Enter`. Now you have a list.

With the cursor inside of your list go to `Table Tools` tab, `Design` tab and check the `Total Row` check-box. An automatically generated total row should appear for your list.

Now go in the cell right bellow the last cell of your list is. In the example above it should be the cell under the cell which holds the *"Descrip 4"* value which, if you followed my steps, should have the word *"Total"* in it. Here press `Ctrl +` (Control and Plus key - usually I use the one from the numeric keypad).

*In this way you will have a new line in your list.* Enter the desired values and the total will be updated automatically.

Comment: Thank You! This will reduce my invoicing and estimating by half!

Comment: Nice answer, John.

Comment: @john is this solution written for 2010? The list references sound like 2003.

Comment: @DavidVandenbos: Yes, it is for 2010. In fact I used XL2010 when I wrote the answer. But it works also for older versions. It might differ only the placement of the check box which enables the Total row singe XL2003 has toolbars while 2007-2010 has ribbons. HTH

Comment: In Excel 2013 I needed to select the whole row to insert a new line using the CTRL+ PLUS.